# Undefined local variable or method error in OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm following [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/) tutorial.

I'm stuck in Step 4:

> Step 4: Creating the Login Page Let’s create our sessions controller.
>
> Run the following code in your terminal to create a new sessions
>   controller, and the new, create, and failure actions.
>
> rails generate controller sessions new create failure

When I enter the command above in the terminal I get this error (after adding my Facebook's application `App ID` and `App Secret`):

> /home/alex/apps/omniauth-tutorial/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:2:in
>   `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method`
>   d0cdb4fe2489xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for #
>   (NameError)

(the 'x's are the rest of the numbers).

I'm using Rails 3.1.3 and this is what I have in my Gemfile:

Any suggestions to fix this?

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-github'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add quotes to the values app id and secret key

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
```

Try this and restart webrick;it should work

Comment: Thanks I tried that but now I'm getting this error (after all files are generated: `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}`

Comment: The problem might be with your facebook callback settings it should be http://localhost:3000/

Comment: here: `Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, "3430xxxxxxxxxx", "d0cdb4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
end` (the 'x's are the rest of the numbers). Is it because I'm setting this on localhost?

Comment: your facebook app settings call back url should be "http://localhost:3000/" with the trailing slash

Comment: Have u got it correct? other wise pls check ur routes.rb and your facebook application settings with correct callback url's ;thats where the problem lies

Comment: I got this: `Error
App Domain: localhost:3000/ is not a valid domain.`